# qemu: could not open gdbserver on device 'tcp::1234'

Tags: android, security, kernel

I have a problem when I study Android kernel Stack-buffer-overflow vulnerability.

Firstly, I create a AVD named "kernel_challenges"

and then, run it using command

```
"emulator64-arm -show-kernel -kernel arch/arm/boot/zImage -avd kernel_challenges -no-boot-anim -no-skin -no-audio -no-window -qemu -monitor unix:/tmp/qemuSocket,server,nowait -s"
```

It work well, then I panic it

[Panic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6shmV.png)

Then, I resart the emulator, but it can't start anymore

[The emulator can't restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeaJs.png)

After restart the Linux, the emulator can start.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, when the emulator panic, we should input q in the gdb debug terminal instead of closing emulator forcely